# CSS transition fade element

Tags: css, css-transitions

I want to fade an element from visible to invisible.

I know I can do this using:

```
element {
  opacity:1;
}

element.fade {
  opacity:0;
  transition: opacity .5s linear;
}
```

The problem with this is that the (now) invisible element is still present, taking up space.

I'd like it to fade and then disappear completely, like if `display:none` was set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hook the `transitionEnd` event and then when the fade finishes you can set `display: none` in that event handler.  Or, you can use a different type of transition that ends with the element taking no space (such as transitioning the height to 0).

To hook the end of the transition, you'd use something like this:

```
// for webkit browsers
node.addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd', function() {
        // set to display: none here
    }, false);
```

Use other prefixes with the transitionEnd event for other browsers.

Comment: That's webkit-only, but CSS transitions are supported by all major browsers now.

Comment: @porneL - yes, you have to use the appropriate browser-specific prefix with the transtionEnd event.

Answer (score 1):

Set a javascript timeout at 0.5s and then just add the extra css

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName(fade)[0];
setTimeout(function() {        
    element.style.display="none"; 
}, 500);
```